# How to use a matrix section in a declarative pipeiline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have the following pipeline. I need this pipeline to run on 4 different nodes at the same time. I have read that using a matrix section within the declarative pipeline is key to making this work. How can I go about doing that with the pipeline below?

```
pipeline 
{
    stages
    {
        stage ('Test')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    def test_proj_choices = ['AD', 'CD', 'DC', 'DISP_A', 'DISP_PROC', 'EGI', 'FD', 'FLT', 'FMS_C', 'IFF', 'liblO', 'libNGC', 'libSC', 'MISCMP_MP', 'MISCMP_GP', 'NAV_MGR', 'RADALT', 'SYS', 'SYSIO15', 'SYSIO42', 'SYSRED', 'TACAN', 'VOR_ILS', 'VPA', 'WAAS', 'WCA']
                    for (choice in test_proj_choices) 
                    {
                        stage ("${choice}") 
                        {
                            echo "Running ${choice}"
                            build job: "UH60Job", parameters: [string(name: "TEST_PROJECT", value: choice), string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_ACTION", value: "all"), string(name: "VIEW_ROOT", value: "myview")] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One helpful article can be found here : https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/

The official documentation here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix

Accordingly, the syntax should be:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Tests') {
            matrix {
                agent any
                axes {
                    axis {
                        name 'CHOICE'
                        values 'AD', 'CD', 'DC', 'DISP_A', 'DISP_PROC', 'EGI', 'FD', 'FLT', 'FMS_C', 'IFF', 'liblO', 'libNGC', 'libSC', 'MISCMP_MP', 'MISCMP_GP', 'NAV_MGR', 'RADALT', 'SYS', 'SYSIO15', 'SYSIO42', 'SYSRED', 'TACAN', 'VOR_ILS', 'VPA', 'WAAS', 'WCA'
                    }
                }
                stages {
                    stage("Test") {
                        steps {
                            echo "Running ${CHOICE}"
                            build job: "UH60Job", parameters: [string(name: "TEST_PROJECT", value: CHOICE), string(name: "SCADE_SUITE_TEST_ACTION", value: "all"), string(name: "VIEW_ROOT", value: "myview")] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your inner `stage` cannot be named dynamically, you'd get a syntax error trying to expand `"${CHOICE}"`.

Comment: It seems to get stuck waiting for the next available executor on the agent nodes. Anyway around this?

Comment: I would like to put a groovy array to the values ... I wonder if its possible.